# jsf send selectOneMenu value as direct request managed bean

Tags: jsf, properties, managed-bean, selectonemenu

I have a selectOneMenu that manages a relation between two Objects A and B.
Where A is fixed and B is selectable via the menu.
On form submit B is send to the bean for further processing (creating and saving relationship object AToB).

**Not working case!**

```
<h:selectOneMenu value=#{b}>
    <!-- b items from bean -->
</h:selectOneMenu>
<h:commandButton action="#{bean.addBToSelA(b)}"/>

<managed-bean>
    <description>B Entity Request Bean</description>
    <managed-bean-name>b</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>B</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

**Working case!**

But if the selectOneMenu value is a nested property of a different managed bean it works. (as example AToB)

```
<h:selectOneMenu value=#{aToB.b}>
    <!-- b items from bean -->
</h:selectOneMenu>
<h:commandButton action="#{bean.addBToSelA(aToB.b)}"/>

<managed-bean>
    <description>AToB Entity Request Bean</description>
    <managed-bean-name>aToB</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>AToB</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

Note: It is enough if my "b" is just a property of a different request managed bean.

Can someone be so kind and explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because JSF has already created the bean instance beforehand. It won't be overridden with the model value if the instance already exist in the scope. Remove the `<managed-bean>` from `faces-config.xml` and it'll work just fine.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you seem to be already using JSF 2.x. Why sticking to the old JSF 1.x style `faces-config.xml` configuration? Just use `@ManagedBean` annotation (on real backing bean classes only, of course).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, will test this later. Those request-scope Entities are just Pojo's from Hibernate without any Annotations at all. They are retrieved from an EAR and are shared across its clients (shall in future). My thoughts were that this way I can keep it independent and different for each client if necessary. If annotations are application/project specific and surely won't be reused I don't mind inserting them into the source code. But still each has pro and cons.

Comment: I can't delete it because I have another form where I can add new B Objects with user inputed properties. So I just have to rename it.